# How can I change the section numbering style for only one chapter?

Tags: sectioning, numbering

I am currently doing this:

```
\chapter{A Chapter}
\renewcommand\thesection{\Roman{section}}
```

But it affects ALL following chapters.  I want to change the style of only this particular chapter.  Is there a way to do that?  Or do I need to manually change back the next chapter?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Quick workaround: use your redefinition inside a group

```
\documentclass{book}

\begin{document}

\begingroup
\chapter{A Chapter}
\renewcommand\thesection{\Roman{section}}
\section{test}

\endgroup

\chapter{B Chapter}
\section{test}

\end{document}
```